# std::thread() and std::ref() cause build errors when used inside of a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I posted a question yesterday but I didn't have a runnable example to give other users. I do now, so I deleted my old post.

I have some code that fails to build when I attempt to make and use `std::threads()` and `std::ref()` inside of a class. I do not understand the error messages that are produced, which all start with the line `error: no matching function for call` or `error: no type named ‘type’`.

I am using Clion and CMake, incase that matters. My file structure is:

```
Personal
--include
----main.h
--src
----main.cpp
----CMakeLists.txt
--CMakeLists.txt
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
# CMAKE version requirement
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

# Project name
project(scrap CXX)

# Configure the build
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
add_compile_options(-W -Wall -ggdb)
include_directories(include)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

# What is being built
add_executable(scrap)
add_subdirectory(src)

# Add external dependencies
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(scrap ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

**src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
# Add targets
target_sources(scrap PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
        )
```

**main.h**

```
#ifndef PERSONAL_MAIN_H
#define PERSONAL_MAIN_H

#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

class ScrapPaper
{
public:
    ScrapPaper();
    static void SpinUpThreads();
    void ThreadFunction1(std::promise<bool> &prom);
    void ThreadFunction2(std::promise<bool> &prom);

private:

};

#endif //PERSONAL_MAIN_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "../include/main.h"

using namespace std;

void ScrapPaper::ThreadFunction1(promise<bool> &prom)
{
    cout << "Thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " working in ThreadFunction1!" << endl;
    sleep(10);

    cout << "Thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " finished sleeping in Function1" << endl;
    prom.set_value_at_thread_exit(true);
}

void ScrapPaper::ThreadFunction2(promise<bool> &prom)
{
    cout << "Thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " working in ThreadFunction2!" << endl;
    sleep(2);
    cout << "Thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " finished sleeping in Function2" << endl;
    prom.set_value_at_thread_exit(true);
}

void ScrapPaper::SpinUpThreads()
{
    promise<bool> promise1;
    future<bool> future1 = promise1.get_future();
    std::thread (&ScrapPaper::ThreadFunction1, ref(promise1)).detach();

    promise<bool> promise2;
    future<bool> future2 = promise2.get_future();
    std::thread (&ScrapPaper::ThreadFunction2, ref(promise2)).detach();

    if (future1.get() && future2.get())
    {
        cout << "Everything was a-okay" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Whoops, there was an error..." << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "In Main..." << endl;
    ScrapPaper::SpinUpThreads();

} // end main
```

Some of the errors that I am getting are:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (ScrapPaper::*)(std::promise<bool>&), std::reference_wrapper<std::promise<bool> > > >::_M_invoke(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (ScrapPaper::*)(std::promise<bool>&), std::reference_wrapper<std::promise<bool> > > >::_Indices)’
  operator()()
  ^~~~~~~~
```

and

```
error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::__invoke_result<void (ScrapPaper::*)(std::promise<bool>&), std::reference_wrapper<std::promise<bool> > >’
```

When the class is taken away and there is just a `main()` and the `ThreadFunction1(...)` and `ThreadFunction2(...)`, the code builds and runs. Am I having a scope problem? Any advice or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use a lambda for this instead of function pointers and explicit references? `std::thread ([&](){ScrapPaper::ThreadFunction1(promise1);});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that since you are using member functions, you need an instance of the class to call the member functions on.  If `SpinUpThreads` wasn't static you could use

```
std::thread (&ScrapPaper::ThreadFunction1, this, ref(promise1)).detach();
std::thread (&ScrapPaper::ThreadFunction2, this, ref(promise2)).detach();
```

but since it is static you have to create an instance of the class to pass to `thread`s constructor.  You can share one object for both calls or give each thread it's own object.  That woulds look like

```
ScrapPaper common;
std::thread (&ScrapPaper::ThreadFunction1, common, ref(promise1)).detach();
std::thread (&ScrapPaper::ThreadFunction2, common, ref(promise2)).detach();

//or

std::thread (&ScrapPaper::ThreadFunction1, ScrapPaper{}, ref(promise1)).detach();
std::thread (&ScrapPaper::ThreadFunction2, ScrapPaper{}, ref(promise2)).detach();
```

---

You can also use a lambda to make the call syntax easier.  If you use a lambda you can write the function call in more natural manner and it would look like

```
ScrapPaper common;
std::thread ([&](){ common.ThreadFunction1(promise1); }).detach();
std::thread ([&](){ common.ThreadFunction2(promise2); }).detach();

//or

std::thread ([&](){ ScrapPaper{}.ThreadFunction1(promise1); }).detach();
std::thread ([&](){ ScrapPaper{}.ThreadFunction2(promise2); }).detach();
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. Does `this` have to be in that location?

Comment: @Kay Yes.  If you are using a member function for a thread the very first parameter after the function needs to be a pointer or object of the class type the function belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

When using `std::thread` to call the member function, the second argument should be an instance of the class (or the pointer to it).

In your case, the code would be

```
 static ScrapPaper p;
 std::thread (&ScrapPaper::ThreadFunction2, p, ref(promise2)).detach();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This made my project build without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of two things. As written, the two thread functions are non-static member functions. You must have an object to call them on, and that's what the other answers have addressed.

But neither of those functions uses any data from a `ScrapPaper` object, so you can change them to **static** member functions and the rest of your code should work without changes. That is, change

```
class ScrapPaper
{
public:
    ScrapPaper();
    static void SpinUpThreads();
    void ThreadFunction1(std::promise<bool> &prom);
    void ThreadFunction2(std::promise<bool> &prom);

private:

};
```

to

```
class ScrapPaper
{
public:
    ScrapPaper();
    static void SpinUpThreads();
    static void ThreadFunction1(std::promise<bool> &prom);
    static void ThreadFunction2(std::promise<bool> &prom);

private:

};
```

Of course, with those changes, the natural question is why `ScrapPaper` is a class, since it has no data and no object-specific behavior. That suggests possibly making `ScrapPaper` a namespace rather than a class. But that's a subject for a different question.

Comment: Thank you for the response! The above code was me trying to figure out how to use threads in a class for a different (much larger) project.